# While / Switch Loop Implementation

Tags: c, while-loop, switch-statement

When I run this code and I hit one of the switch's breaks (excluding case 'x') the first printf statement outputs twice. I'm not sure why this happens. Wondering if anybody can see it right from the code without needing the functions to actually run the program.

```
int main(void)
{
   int key;
   char command, word[STRINGMAX];
   struct data_node *first=NULL, *ptr, *new_node;

   while (command)
   {
      printf("Enter a list command (+-flx): ");
      scanf("%c", &command);
      switch(command)
      {
      case '+' :
         printf("'+' detected\n");
         printf("Enter key data: ");
         scanf("%d", &key);
         printf("What string to store?: ");
         scanf("%s", &word);
         first = ptr = insert(&first, key, word);
         break;

      case '-' :
         printf("'-' detected\n");
         printf("Enter key data: ");
         scanf("%d", &key);
         delete(&first, key);
         break;
      case 'f' :
         printf("'f' detected\n");
         printf("Enter a key data: ");
         scanf("%d", &key);
         find_node(first, key);
         break;
      case 'l' :
         printf("'l' detected\n");
         dump_list(first);
         break;
      case 'x' :
         printf("Goodbye.\n");
         exit(0);
      default :
         break;
      }
   }
   return (0);
}
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify the issue? I don't understand what is expected or what actually happens. Maybe sample input and output?

Comment: Are you referring to the first printf inside the while loop or the first one inside each case block?

Comment: There's probably something left in the buffer. You can call scanf again at the end of the while loop to confirm

Comment: Since you're scanning char by char, most likely you're seeing the character chosen on the first iteration, and the line feed on the second.

Comment: What I think would help is to add a space before % in.......scanf("%c", &command); so it looks like ..........scanf(" %c", &command);

Comment: Unrelated issue:  You should initialize `command` prior to the start of the loop to some non-zero value. If it happens to be zero, the loop will not run at all.

Comment: @Survaf93 your idea helped. Works like I need it to now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a getchar() after reading a number and a string as scanf leaves the new line character in the input stream. It is preferable to use fgets().

Vivek